# Main differences between Ubuntu Studio 12.04 and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-studio

What are the differences between Ubuntu Studio 12.04 and Ubuntu 12.04

Have a nice time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **Desktop environment**: Ubuntu 12.04 uses Unity as shell over Gnome desktop environment while Ubuntu Studio 12.04 uses Xfce as
- **Linux kernel**: Ubuntu Studio 12.04 uses realtime kernel (for reducing the amount of latency, which is extremely beneficial for audio work) while Ubuntu 12.04 uses generic kernel([more about kernel types](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/RealTimeKernel)).
- **Installation**: Ubuntu 12.04 has live CD for installation but Ubuntu Studio 12.04 only has live DVD.
- **Applications**: Ubuntu Studio 12.04 contain a lot more pre-installed multimedia software (several audio, video and graphical applications) than Ubuntu 12.04.
- **Appearance**: Ubuntu Studio 12.04 has blue-on-black theme instead of Ubuntu's default purple and orange and also a new sound theme replaces the default Ubuntu theme.
- **JACK Sound System** : Along with the ubiquitous Pulse Audio sound server, the powerful JACK sound server is also included in Ubuntu Studio. Both are already configured to work well together.
- **System Configuration** : There is a different configuration of the system so as to "**not-limit**" you audio/video processing.

Comment: Live CD support for Ubuntu Desktop will not be available from 12.10 versions.

Answer (score 0):

**What Is Ubuntu Studio**

Ubuntu Studio is an officially recognized flavour of Ubuntu aimed at dedicated multimedia production workstations. Based on the solid standard edition of Ubuntu, it comes with a suite of the best open source applications aimed at both multimedia enthusiasts as well as trained professionals.

Ubuntu Studio is completely free to use, modify and redistribute. Your only limitation is your imagination.

To better understand how Ubuntu Studio differs from the basic edition of Ubuntu, we will compare the two.

**Ubuntu Studio vs. Ubuntu**

Some differences are immediately more evident between Ubuntu Studio and plain, vanilla Ubuntu. These would include a different theme and background, as well as a different battery of installed applications. But Ubuntu Studio is more than just Ubuntu with a slicker theme and extra packages installed. There are several subtle and pervasive differences.

**Obvious Differences**

Theme and Artwork - Gone is the familiar brown and orange! Remember, we're creative human beings. Probably the most obvious difference is the new creative theme.

Multi-Media Applications - Ubuntu Studio is chock-full of pre-installed audio, video and graphical applications including JACK, Ardour, GIMP and Kino.

**Subtle, Powerful Differences**

Real Time Kernel - Ubuntu Studio uses the Ingo Molnar PREEMPT patched real-time kernel (for more information about the real-time kernel, take a look at the RTWiki FAQ). This helps to reduce the amount of latency, which is extremely beneficial for audio work. The low levels of latency that can be achieved in Linux with the real-time kernel can also surpass those available under Windows and Mac.

System Configuration - The Ubuntu Studio team has already configured the Ubuntu Studio system to help maximize the real-time kernel. The user is included in the audio group and the limits.conf file is specifically configured.

JACK Sound System - Along with the ubiquitous Pulse Audio sound server, the powerful JACK sound server is also included in Ubuntu Studio. Both are already configured to work well together.

[source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/What%20Is%20Ubuntu%20Studio)